# How can I edit a value of User without signing the User out?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, session, session-variables, session-cookies

I would like to add a column to `users` called `points`, and update it at different times. However, when I change a value of a User column, the User is signed out, since the remember token for the user gets changed, and doesn't match the one stored locally.

I can manually sign in the user each time I update a column in the controller, but I want to avoid this if possible (and be able to update from the model). Is there a way I can update the User without signing them out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized the problem was a new token is generated with a before_save callback whenever a User is saved. So there are two ways I can fix this:

1. Change before_save to before_create.
2. User `update_column` to update a column without calling the before_save callbacks.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know what authentication system you are using, but just changing the schema or updating a user's attributes doesnt require a user to login again on most common rails auth systems (Devise, Authlogic, etc...)

Comment: It's not with a gem. The authentication is similar to the one used by Railscasts and Railstutorial. http://railscasts.com/episodes/250-authentication-from-scratch http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-in-sign-out

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing would be to store `@user.id` in your session variable, rather than the whole `User` object.  With that approach, even after editing, you will keep a stable `id` field that you can reference.

This has a few benefits:

1. It's more secure.  Rails sessions are difficult to tamper, but easy to read. So you now don't have to worry about any secure or semisecure data in your session cookie that would be leaked by embedding the whole user
2. The whole object is potentially big. Every request has a serialized `User` object going back and forth for no good reason.

It's easy to wire this into your application controller so it's transparent that an `id` is used rather than a real User object.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
   def current_user
      User.find(session[:user_id])
   end
....
```

Of course you'll add error handling for a not-logged-in user, but that general approach will keep your code clean, and abstract away the a User's data contents from the idea of a User's identifier.